# GWT Java - "getWidget()" is deprecated - what replaces it?

Tags: java, gwt, gwtupload

I am loading images using code (please see below) I found through stackoverflow. However, I now notice that the "getWidget()" is deprecated. Rather than wait until this is no longer available I would like to fix this now. What should I use instead of "getWidget()" please?

```
// Add a finish handler which will load the image once the upload finishes
            existingdefaultUploader.addOnFinishUploadHandler(onReplaceFinishUploaderHandler);
            existingdefaultUploader.getFileInput().getWidget().setStyleName("customButton");
            existingdefaultUploader.getFileInput().getWidget().setSize("100px", "20px");
```

Regards,

Glyn

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `.asWidget()` instead.

Sometimes classes comment what method to use instead of the deprecated one.
 In this case there is no comment. However you can look at the [source code](https://github.com/manolo/gwtupload/blob/master/core/src/main/java/gwtupload/client/IFileInput.java) to see how the class itself implements the deprecated method:

```
@Deprecated
public Widget getWidget() {
  return asWidget();
}
```

EDIT:
As mentioned in the comments, the Javadoc of the [latest version](https://github.com/manolo/gwtupload/blob/204a857b920e5f2cb1bbcc2d51d6ee84af8b5f0c/core/src/main/java/gwtupload/client/IFileInput.java#L314-L319) even tells you what to use instead of the deprecated method.

Comment: And more precisely: https://github.com/manolo/gwtupload/blob/204a857b920e5f2cb1bbcc2d51d6ee84af8b5f0c/core/src/main/java/gwtupload/client/IFileInput.java#L314-L319 In other words: just read the javadoc.